# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in

Tags: php, laravel

Im getting a fatal error in my php code, I'm more of a SQL guy here so a little bit of guidance would be much appreciated.

```
if (isset(Auth::check() || Auth::attempt())) {  $auth_id = Auth::user()->id; }
```

Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in. I thought the code is right but perhaps I am writing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is totally wrong:

```
(isset(Auth::check() || Auth::attempt()))
```

`isset` checks for the existence of a variable. You're not doing that. You're testing for the existence of the result of a logical `OR` operation.

By definition, a logical operation will **ALWAYS** produce a result, so there is exactly ZERO point in testing for the existence of that result. You most likely just want to test if that `OR` operation evalutes to true/false, in which case `isset()` is utterly useless anyways.

Try

```
if (Auth::check() || Auth::attempt()) { ... }
```

instead. Or whatever logic is appropriate for the return values you get from those two calls.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I wan'ts aware that a logical operation will always produce a result, yes I believe that is correct, I will check the accept when its available momentarily. Thanks for the help here.